# Reverse for 'ads' not found. 'ads' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I'm working on my project for a course and I'm totally stuck right now.
I would like to invoke another Html in the Index file that contains the contents of a model
The index actually works properly and is called from the post model correctly but not from the ads model.
Can anybody see what I'm missing?

URLS.py

```
    from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import *

app_name = 'post'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index_view, name="index"),
    path('create/', create_view, name="create"),
    path('ads/', ads_view, name="ads"),

    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', detail_view, name="detail"),
    #re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/ads/$', ads_view, name="ads"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/update/$', update_view, name="update"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', delete_view, name="delete"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/search/$', delete_view, name="search"),


]
```

views.py

```
def ads_view(request,id):

ads = get_object_or_404(Ads,id=2)

return render(request, "post/ads.html", {"ads":ads})
```

base.html

```
    {% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PhoneBook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        {% block header %}

        {% include 'header.html' %}
        {% url 'ads' %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% include 'message.html' %}

        {% block body%}



        {% endblock %}
    </div>
        <script src="{% static '/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static '/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

ads.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-md-8 offset-md-2">

        <div class="card-body">

            <p>{{ ads.ads_text }} </p>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> > NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'ads' not found. 'ads' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Request Method:    GET Request
> >     URL:  http://192.168.202.88:8000/ Django Version: 3.0 Exception
> >     Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for 'ads' not found.
> >     'ads' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not completely correct.
`get_object_or_404()` only return **one** object.
so, it isn't necessary to use for loop in template.
Your `ads` is actually one Ads object.

You might want to have a look at the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Instead, you can just type `{{ads.ads_text}}`.

Besides, `{% url 'ads' %}` will return the **url** of `path('ads/', ads_view, name="ads")`.
[Url in Template Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed 
No need ads.html

In body Of the Index.html

```
{% for i in ads %}
{{ ads.ads_text }}

{%endfor%}
```